# Entity Framework & Sql Server 2012 spatial

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm struggling to find any concrete performance of Entity Framework paired with SQL server 2012.

We're looking at storing nearly a million points in a database an right now the most common scenario would be to find all points within radius of N.

I've mocked up a small prototype using EF5 and it seems fine. However, a senior developer has mentioned that in his opinion EF is bloated and I should consider using a micro-orm or even pure ADO.NET as EF is a bloated monster (lol).

Performance is crucial on this project and I would like to know if anyone has experience to prove this guy otherwise (or right for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation will be inconsistent; but my experience has shown any commodity DAL has a performance hit considering you have overhead of objects and logic you won't use as expected by the vendor. While EF5 with SQL2012 is optimized by Microsoft for use together, you will find that targeted .Net logic with well written and indexed SQL2012 will be a tighter solution.
Even using EF there is still a level of functionality for your spatial work that the EF just doesn't really support; so you will need to extend further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Guess I owe someone a beer :)

Comment: It's funny, the Bing crew just published this blog entry on using EF5 with SQL/Azure and Bing Maps... http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/07/31/how-to-create-a-spatial-web-service-that-connects-a-database-to-bing-maps-using-ef5.aspx

Comment: Using EF5/6 you really shouldn't have any performance problems given a properly written EF query.  Of course you can write some pretty bad ones, but that isn't EF's fault and in many cases, it can even optimize away some poorly written ones.